# Identifying deleted character in UITextField or UITextView

Tags: ios

I need to identify the deleted character. For example, when I delete a character "@", I need to perform some actions. Is there any easy way to do this? Or do I need to keep the recently typed character in a variable and check the range.length == 0 in shouldChangeCharactersInRange?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, it should be just like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *textToChange  = [[textField text] substringWithRange:range];
    NSRange rangeOld = [textToChange rangeOfString:@"@"];
    NSRange rangeNew = [string rangeOfString:@"@"];
    if (rangeOld.location != NSNotFound && rangeNew.location == NSNotFound ) {
        [self userDidRemoveAtSign];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Explanation: Yep, `userDidRemoveAtSign` is your custom method when user deletes '@' sign. This code resides in UITextField **delegate**. Every time user change text in UITextField, delete, replace or appent characters, textfield send this message

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

to delegate. In this method I check if @ sign is cotained in replaced text, and if it is contained in replacement.

Comment: Hi can you just explain what the above code do? also what's the method "userDidRemoveAtSign"? Isn't a custom method?

Answer (score 1):

Yes as you said you will have to keep the last set of characters in a NSString and then when text changes compare it with the new string

Answer (score 0):

> You can do this in swift by this way, you will get deleted character

let strDeletedChar = (textView.text as NSString).substringWithRange(range)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the deletede char in a method of UITextView Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
   NSString *deletedChar = [textView.text substringWithRange:range];
   if ([deletedChar isEqualToString:@"@"]) {
       // do something
       return YES;
   }else{
    // do something
    return YES;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITextView Delegate Swift 5 version:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    guard let txt = textView.text, let txtRange = Range(range, in: txt) else {
        return false
    }
    let subString: Substring = txt[txtRange]
    if  subString == "(searchString)" {
        // do something
        return true
    }
}
```